# Laravel/Carbon Timestamp 0000-00-00 00:00:00 or Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, laravel-4

I have a timestamp in the DB and am trying to get the swine to save. I either get an issue where the `MySQL` timestamp is blank or I get an error. The format posted is UK standard.

Posting data, I have tried some of the following:

```
$user['crb_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data['crb_date']);

$user['crb_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data['crb_date'])->toDateTimeString();

// Plus many other more std date(), strtodate() combos
```

On my Model, I have custom getDates which will convert the dates to Carbon:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return [
        'last_login',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'dob',
        'crb_date'
    ];
}
```

Now, if I update the user with the carbon date, I get the following issue:

`Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing`

However, if I `dd($user['crb_date']` after the second Carbon date conversion I get

`string '2011-05-01 11:20:23' (length=19)`

Which looks pretty good to me.

If I remove the accessor on the Model, I get it to post, however, I get the blank timestamp

`0000-00-00 00:00:00`

I've also tried putting a mutator on the model to set the date there, but issue is exactly the same.

Any ideas what I can do to get this to work? I think it might be something to do with the accessor causing the issue, but need that to work with the dates better afterwards.

Many thanks for taking the time to help.

This is the mutator I have tried - It was set on the Model. However, the above code (Carbon::createFormFormat... is currently in my repo:

```
public function setCrbDateAttribute($value)
{
     $this->attributes['crb_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i', $value);
}
```

The Accessor:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return [
        'last_login',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'dob',
        'crb_date'
    ];
}
```

---

#### SORTED!

Thanks to WereWolf's answer below, I tweaked the Model mutator and it is now working like a charm. Here is what I have now:

```
public function setCrbDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['crb_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

Comment: When you say you 'remove the accessor to the Model' is that removing your date attribute from `getDates()` or remove from `getFooAttribute()`?

Comment: Where is your `accessor` method ?

Comment: @JofryHS, Yes. I have removed the entire getDates() method and when posted, I get blank timestamp.

Comment: Do you have an accessor method in your model like `getCreatedAtAttribute` or so ?

Comment: @WereWolf - The Alpha, I will update the OP. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `date` string, for example, you have this:

```
public function setCrbDateAttribute($value)
{
     $this->attributes['crb_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i', $value);
}
```

Now, if there is a date like `10-12-2014` then this error will occur because the `hour` and `minute` is missing. So you make sure that the date contains all the pars and also make sure that the date string contains `-` as a separator not `/`.

In other words, check the `$value` before you use `Carbon` and make sure your date string contains exactly the same formatted string you've used in the method.

This also happens in an `accessor` method, so check the date value first before you use it in `Carbon::createFromFormat()`.

If you are getting the date from user input then validate the date before using it using `date` or `date_format:format` rule, [check the validation here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-date-format).

Comment: Thanks. however, I have used this: $user['crb_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data['crb_date'])->toDateTimeString(); which produces the string: 2011-05-01 11:20:23 Which should be fine right? The mutator is something I have been experimenting with. Do you think I should be working with it on the Model and not the Repo then? I'll have a play. Cheers.

Comment: I think it should be in your model's method.

Comment: Nailed it, Thanks WereWolf - What a legend. I'll update the OP to display what I did and +1 when the limit is up. Many thanks dude - What a legend.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to know that it was helpful and +1 as well :-)

Comment: Carbon itself should be checking if a string has the correct format.