# Laravel 5 and Eloquent between two dates from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am a beginner with Laravel 5. I have a table: users with columns CreateDate, Type and Channel.

I have a list with users and I choose in View: Trans StartDate, Trans EndDate, Type and Channel.

I want to show: Tras `StartDate < CreateDate < Trans EndDate` with Type and Channel. `name="time_start", "time_end", "type", "channel"`.

My Route:

```
Route::post('user', 'CSKHController@index');
```

My Controller:

```
public function index() {

    $start = Input::get ( 'time_start' );
    $end = Input::get ( 'time_end' );      

    $articles = KhachHang::all()->whereBetween('CreateDate', [$start, $end])->get();

    return view('admin/layouts/test', compact('stt','article'))->withDetails($articles);

}
```

Help me please!

Comment: And what is your question? Please be more specific and show us where your problem lies and what you have done to solve it.

Comment: I want to show data follow: Tras StartDate < CreateDate < Trans EndDate with Type and Channel. I try with my code but it not run right.

Comment: What is `KhachHang`? Does this model has a `CreateDate` attribute?

Comment: I have model KhachHang: class KhachHang extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

Answer (score 6):

## Laravel 5.*

This is an example of how i used eloquent between in a **laravel 5.6** project.

**my-view.blade.php**

simplified html form:

```
<form action="my-route" method="POST">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="date" name="from">

    <input type="date" name="to">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**MyController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

// ...

$request->validate([

    'from'        => 'required|date',
    'to'          => 'required|date',
]);

$from    = Carbon::parse($request->from)
                 ->startOfDay()        // 2018-09-29 00:00:00.000000
                 ->toDateTimeString(); // 2018-09-29 00:00:00

$to      = Carbon::parse($request->to)
                 ->endOfDay()          // 2018-09-29 23:59:59.000000
                 ->toDateTimeString(); // 2018-09-29 23:59:59

$models  = Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();

// do whatever you want with the query results...
```

---

Additional resources

[Date range with whereBetween](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/daterange-with-wherebetween#reply=283013)

[Converting a carbon date to mysql timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012671/4325011)

Answer (score 3):

To check between two dates, you could use this (among other options):

```
$articles = KhachHang::where('CreateDate', '>=', $start)
                     ->where('CreateDate', '<=', $end)->get();
```

You have to be sure that the date format is 'Y-m-d', or the code will not work.

Comment: Should be using `whereBetween()`. That's really the whole reason it is there.

Comment: @jonlink I can not mix `where` and `whereBetween` when I collect conditions (`name like 'hello' and date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-01'` )

Comment: @flaschenpost sure you can :) I do stuff like that all the time. I'm not sure about the specifics of what you are doing, what your trying to accomplish, and what isn't working, but you can absolutely use `whereBetween()` alongside `where()`

Comment: @flaschenpost ex. `MyClass::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->where('name', 'LIKE', '%hello%')->toSql()` yields: `"select * from my_class where created_at between ? and ? and name LIKE ?"`, which is what I'd expect to get. So if I do: `MyClass::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->where('name', 'LIKE', '%hello%')->get()` the expected results are returned.

Comment: thanks, that's true. but I could not mix it with `if`. I had it like 'if (...name...){$co[] = [name,=,$n;]} if (...date...){ $co[] = [ ... date ...];}` and then put the $co into the where(). But you are right, there seems to be a way to chain it with if() between.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but the answer isn't great. Use `whereBetween()`, which has been around since at least 5.0 [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

`$articles = KhachHang::whereBetween('CreateDate', [$start, $end])->get();`

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this to your Eloquent query.

`->whereBetween('your_field', [$from, $to])->get();`