# How to insert date format YY-MM into database?

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to get the the Year and Month from the user and insert them into the database. 
i am using input type month so that the user can send only the Year and the Month.

```
<input type="month" name="date_from"/>
<input type="month" name="date_to"/>
```

and this is my model

```
function setDateFromAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date_from'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createDateFromFormat('Y-m', $value);
}


function setDateToAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date_to'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createDateToFormat('Y-m', $value);
}


protected $fillable = [
    'date_from',
    'date_to',
];
```

and data is saved as 0000.00.00
the data type in my database for these two inputs is

```
timestamp
```

i do not know what i am doing wrong here. please help

Comment: why do you have input="month",  that shouldn't exist. That should be a text-> <input type="text" name="date_from"/>

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? Did you find the answer on your own?

Comment: @Mubo using the input="month" i am able to get the month and year only from the user directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ted Stresen-Reuter

Sorry for the late reply couldn't find a solution that works within the model. tried your method which i have tried before with minor changes.

thanks a lot for trying to help me.. i found a method to complete this inside the controller which i will not recommend, but this was the best i was able to find which works and i was on a tight schedule.

```
'date_from' => isset($date_from[$key]) ? date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date_from[$key])) : '',
'date_to' => isset($date_to[$key]) ? date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date_to[$key])) : '',
```

the type timestamp accepts at least dates in full formats. as i know how i pass the data from blade to the controller i was able to add a date method and within it a strttotime method to convert my YY-MM into YY-MM-DD and the date that is inserted by default will be 01.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `createDateFromFormat` as a valid Carbon method in the documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Likewise, there does not appear to be any `createDateToFormat` method.

`Carbon::createFromFormat()` returns a Carbon object, not a string or equivalent MySQL timestamp, so, assuming you change your code to be:

```
$this->attributes['date_from'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m', $value)->toDateTimeString();
```

It should provide the results you are looking for.

References:
[Converting a carbon date to mysql timestamp.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220091/converting-a-carbon-date-to-mysql-timestamp)