# updateOrCreate does not match Carbon date

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `Laravel Framework 6.16.0` and I am creating from a string a date object so that I can input it in my db:

```
$transaction_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tradeDate);
$filling_Date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $fillingDate, 'UTC');

$product = Product::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'price' => trim($price),
        'qty' => $qty,
        'companies_id' => $company->id,
        'persons_id' => $person->id,
        'amount_range' => $owned,
        'filling_date' => $filling_Date,
        'transaction_date' => $transaction_date,
    ],
    []
);
```

When running the above query my product does not get found as `$filling_Date` and `$transaction_date` are not matched in the database, even if my product already exists.

I am guessing, the reason is that I am creating a "new" Carbon object.

Any suggestions how to match the `filling_date` and `transaction_date` in the database?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Ypu are not actually create anything, the first condition is for checking, your 2nd condition is blank https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods somehow, you need to foramt your Carbon `$transaction_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tradeDate)->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Try casting the values in your model and let Laravel handle it https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012671/11801683

Comment: @STA the first array is the wheres but if it can't find a record it will create a new instance with those attributes (first array) then fill with the second array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this when converting a string to a date with Carbon

```
$date = Carbon::parse($yourStringDate);
```